# Reading DOM content from a background script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, background, content-script

Let's say there are two websites: `x.com` and `y.com`. Here is what I have done so far:

1. When a button is clicked on `x.com`, send a `message` to a background script.
2. The background script opens a new tab to `y.com`.

However, now that the tab to `y.com` has opened, how can I read from the DOM from `y.com` and use that info in the content script that is running on `x.com`?

---

Here is my code so far:

**content.js** (Content script that runs for `x.com`)

```
var btn = document.querySelector('my-btn')

// Send message when btn is clicked
btn.addEventListener('click', message) 

function message() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: 'Get Y data' }, null, function() {
    // I want to use data from `y.com` here somehow
  })
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (response.message !== 'Get Y data') {
    return
  }

  var url = '...'

  chrome.tabs.create({ active: true, url: url }, function (tab) {
    // How do I read DOM from this new `tab` and send it back to content script?
  })
})
```

Comment: You could inject code into the newly created tab (that of `y.com`) and use the injected script to retrieve the data you want and then comunicate back to the background script that will pass the date to `content.js` via a message.

Comment: Hmm, that sounds doable. Are you familiar with what method I can use to inject a script into the tab I created?

Comment: [**`chrome.tabs.executeScript`**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) should do it.